# How to embolden white areas in a MatPlotLib image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have read in an picture of a word in Python using MatPlotLib, inverted it and would like to make all white areas larger to embolden the word. How could I do this?

My assumption is that I would need to look at all pixels within a range *r* of the white pixels and color them white as well. Is this correct?

Please find the code, the example and the desired result below. The dimensions of the image are (465, 748), and

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import pandas as pd

# Code to transform RGB-image into GrayScale and subsequently into inverted BW image.
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    # Convert RGB to GrayScale
    gray_value = np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

    # Invert GrayScale.
    gray_value = 1 - gray_value

    # Apply a threshold.
    gray_value[gray_value >= 0.5] = 1
    gray_value[gray_value < 0.5] = 0
    return gray_value

# Read in image.
img = mpimg.imread('Data/Development/Image_Test.png')     

# BW-scale.
gray = rgb2gray(img)    

# Show image.
plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```

The source image: [image]

The desired result: [image]

Comment: Invert and dilate?

Comment: I have added the lines


    # Dilate
    gray = ndimage.binary_dilation( gray, iterations = 10 ).astype( gray.dtype )

after the rgb2gray step and indeed, I have what I need now.

Comment: @AVS If you have come up with a solution you should add an answer then accept it, don't edit it into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to let the white areas [dilate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html). In this solution I have taken *r* = 10 pixels, by letting the dilation run for 10 iterations.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import pandas as pd

# Code to transform RGB-image into GrayScale and subsequently into inverted BW    image.
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    # Convert RGB to GrayScale
    gray_value = np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

    # Invert GrayScale.
    gray_value = 1 - gray_value

    # Apply a threshold.
    gray_value[gray_value >= 0.5] = 1
    gray_value[gray_value < 0.5] = 0
    return gray_value

# Read in image.
img = mpimg.imread('Data/Development/Image_Test.png')     

# BW-scale.
gray = rgb2gray(img)    

# Dilate the white areas.
gray = ndimage.binary_dilation( gray, iterations = 10 ).astype( gray.dtype )

# Show image.
plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```